# java class import to jsp and create object issue

Tags: java, class, jsp, servlets

Ok, so I completely scratched that direction. I'm just not familiar enough with servlet doget/doPost/remapping stuff. I have no one who knows about it so I'm flying blind.

I do, however, know how to do java programming. I just wanted to create a class so I could maintain an object oriented approach to the web site. I can easily create a class within a jsp 
with the standard

```
 public class foo{

 public foo
 {
  //constructor
 }

 public String getName()
 {
  return "some name";
 }

}
```

But, how do I do this in a .java/.class file and import it into a jsp for use? This is essentially the same question, different approach.

Comment: Post the code for the HelloWorld class, it looks like the package definition and/or class name is incorrect.

Comment: So you have a HelloWorld package as well as a HellowWorld class?  Why do you have the .java file deployed in classes?

Comment: because I don't know what I'm doing just yet lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map your Servlet. Don't use import for a Servlet. See 
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 0):

> I have both the HelloWorld.java and HelloWorld.class in the
>   web-inf/classes folder.

Make sure the HelloWorld.class is in WEB-INF/classes/com/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.class and the HelloWorld.java is in the package com.HelloWorld before it is compiled to the class file.